# Why is the inserted text in my TinyMCE text editor being edited?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to allow a user to insert some custom tags into the text editor using a nested menu item.  Here is a few examples of some of the tags that they can insert:

`<<TYER>>`,
`<<CTPN>>`,
`<<TAL6>>`

On the button click, the editor is inserting `<>` into the editor instead of the actual text that is appearing in the console.  I assume this is happening because the editor is set up to insert HTML tags when it sees the symbols `<` and `>` surrounding text.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<TYER>>` will produce <> because the browser has parsed the text `<TYER>` as an element and the surrounding `<>` tags are shown on the screen because it's invalid HTML and the browser has assumed it's text.

To make the less-than and greater-than signs appear as text on the screen, you need to encode the values.

`&lt;&lt;TYER&gt;&gt;` will produce `<<TYER>>`

`&lt;&lt;CTPN&gt;&gt;` will produce `<<CTPN>>`

`&lt;&lt;TAL6&gt;&gt;` will produce `<<TAL6>>`